# How to use console.trace to see the functionality of each chained function?

Tags: javascript, trace, traceback

I have a set of functions and they are linked to each other. I want to see what was the value of a variable during each of these function execution. I don't want to use console.log.

```js
function applydiscountA(itemPrice){
    itemPrice = itemPrice*0.95;
  applydiscountB(itemPrice);
    } 
function applydiscountB(itemPrice){
    itemPrice = itemPrice*0.85;
  applydiscountC(itemPrice);
    } 
function applydiscountC(itemPrice){
    itemPrice = itemPrice*0.85;
  console.trace(itemPrice);

    } 
let itemPrice = 2000;
applydiscountA(itemPrice);
```

Is there anyway in javascript to see the how the value got updated during the function calls using console.trace().

Comment: No. But you could of course collect the values in an array and pass that on to the next call, and finally output the array. Is this really your code? Because that is a very strange way to do things. You can use `reduce` to make that calculation from an array of given percentages.

Comment: No, `console.trace` does not do what you think it does. You're not updating a value, and the value doesn't keep a history. You're creating lots of new values, and are creating and updating multiple different variables (although they go by the same name, they're in different scopes).

Comment: What you are actually looking for is a debugger. Put a breakpoint at the innermost function, then you can inspect the different variables (even in other functions on the call stack) at that point.

Answer (score 0):

No, once a variable is out of scope, you cannot get access to its value, not with `trace` either. Every `discountX` function has its own `itemPrice` variable, and it is only accessible within that function scope.

However, if your use case is to apply several discounts to an original price, and you want to keep track of all intermediate results, then don't use this pattern, but loop over the percentages, like this:

```js
const discounts = [
    { name: "A", pct: 0.95 },
    { name: "B", pct: 0.85 },
    { name: "C", pct: 0.85 }
];

function applyDiscounts(itemPrice, discounts) {
    return discounts.map(function({name, pct}) {
         itemPrice *= pct;
         return { name, itemPrice };
    });
}

let itemPrice = 2000;
let priceEvolution = applyDiscounts(itemPrice, discounts);
console.log("original price", itemPrice);
console.log(priceEvolution);
console.log("final price", priceEvolution[priceEvolution.length-1].itemPrice);
```